# Long shot -- Possible to have a static class member with lambdas that access non-static members?

Tags: c++

So this is what I have:

```
struct Foo {
    std::string name;
    //etc

    std::map<std::string, std::function<void(Parser&)>> parse_strategy = { 
        { "name", [&](Parser& p) { name = p.read_string(); } },
    };
}
```

I'd like `parse_strategy` to be a static member -- is that possible? If not I could think of some other way to get what I want.

Comment: Could you not give it a `Foo&` parameter (Or be a pointer to a member function)? How were you planning to select which instance to selecte a non-static member from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Just like with any static member function, there is no object context, so whose `name` would be captured?

Lambdas don't change the meaning of static member functions.

Answer (score 1):

No. Static, like in other languages, means it belongs to the class. Classes don't have "default objects," so if you try to get a non-static member variable out of the class the compiler will throw up its hands in frustration, because where is it getting this `name` information from? The error would look something like

`Error: Cannot use non-static member variable in a static context.`

Lambdas don't change this.

Comment: Fixed. Comment now says "Error: ..." instead of "Linker error: ..."

Comment: Also fixed. Comment now only contains second "possible" error message (the other being blatantly impossible).

Comment: There you go ;) You could just have run it to find out what the error would be :P